# diff multiple originals versus backups

Tags: unix, sed, diff

I have a folder with 5 files. I decide I want to do some search and replace on them using sed. Problem is, I need to keep track of the changes. So I make a backup folder "bak" which has all the copes of the original files.

There are now 10 files total. 5 originals and 5 backups.

I would like to run a sed command over the originals and then compare them to the backup to keep track of changes.

would this be as simple as

```
diff * ./backup_folder/*
```

The above code doesn't work but it illustrates the concept. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps put your backup folder in a different location (i.e. not a subdirectory of your current folder) - maybe in the parent of your current folder. Then a simple:

```
diff -r ../backup_folder .
```

or

```
diff -r /path/to/backup_folder .
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in *; do diff "$f" ./backup_folder/"$f"; done
```